# What is a good handbook for behavioral economics?

Tags: reference-request, behavioral-economics

I recently got interested in behavioral economics because it seems to have a lot of interesting applications in other fields such as macroeconomics. I managed to find a lot of interesting sources on development of behavioral models but I would like to get my hands on some handbook that is a behavioral economics' equivalent of lets say Varian Microeconomic Analysis or something like MWG microeconomic theory. Are there some comparable behavioral handbooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sanjit Dhami's [*The Foundations of Behavioral Economic Analysis*](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/the-foundations-of-behavioral-economic-analysis-9780198715535?cc=ca&lang=en&) is arguably the most comprehensive review of the work in behavioral economics to date.

Comment: Thanks I checked it in the library today it’s exactly what I was looking for!